# Is there a word or phrase in Italian for a woman in her sixties or seventies who is always dating young men?

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

These women are usually celebrities: movie stars, socialites, journalists, etc, and they usually make a point of always dating men who are a few decades younger than they are.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think there is an exact traslation for English *cougar*, the Italian *tardona* doesn't imply that the woman is dating a young man but only that she is old and behaves as if she's young (and actually she's ridiculous). However, I prefer men older than me hahaha

Comment: As far as I know there is not in standard Italian language; actually I don't even know what the English word would be! Maybe in dialect I know some word suitable for the case, but very vulgar.

Comment: @FrancescoAnastasio: In English is *cougar* woman.

Comment: There is an old phrase to indicate an older woman who more or less routinely, more or less cheaply ;-), would introduce young cadets to sex. It is _nave scuola_ ("school ship").

Comment: @LSerni  That's not the case here. I mean women who date and eventually marry men who are much younger.  As CarLaTex mentioned, the English equivalent is "a cougar"

Comment: @Centaurus , I know. That's why I made it a comment and not an answer; I hope that someone might find it useful yet.

Comment: @LSerni A *nave scuola* is a (sex) expert woman who teaches to inexpert men, she could be also young hahaha! There is a sentence of the Cassazione about this insult: http://www.lastampa.it/2014/09/12/italia/i-tuoi-diritti/responsabilita-e-sicurezza/cassazione-vietato-dire-a-una-donna-sei-nave-scuola-BqjnIziCJm5eBqazVvDpIP/pagina.html

Comment: L'espressione  ***dietro liceo davanti museo*** può essere usata in questo senso: http://www.giovannagallo.it/chi-sono-le-fighe-di-legno

Comment: I do not think there exists a word with the same connotations of the English *cougar*. The proposed *tardona* has more of a connotation of a woman who dress in an age-inappropriate kind of way despite her age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the term ***[tardona](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=tardona)*** to suggest a mature woman who dresses and behaves as a young woman. I think the term may well be used  to refer to the context you are suggesting:

> - donna di mezza età che si comporta, si veste ecc. come una donna più giovane pensando di essere attraente.

Garzanti

Note also that the term ***[Milf](http://dilei.it/sesso-e-psiche/origine-e-significato-del-termine-milf/425106/)*** is becoming more and more common in Italy:

> Il termine Milf è ormai entrato nel linguaggio comune, specialmente di quello dei ragazzi di oggi.

Comment: But, see my comment to the question, the Italian *tardona* doesn't imply that the woman is dating a young man but only that she is old and behaves as if she's young (and actually she's ridiculous).

Comment: @CarLaTeX - I saw your comment but I disagree. The term "tardona" is actually the term we would use whenever we see a mature woman with a younger man. Also: why would  a mature person (man or woman)  dress and behave like a younger person  to look "more attractive"  (as the dictionary says)?  I think this term has a  "sexual" connotation that we (Italians)   are relactant  to explicitly recognise, probably for cultural reasons. The fact that a mature woman dates younger men is something still frowned upon socially, though things are changing quite rapidly in that respect.

Comment: I would use *tardona* for a woman that dresses like a young one even if she is dating old men...

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Yes, that was the usual context where we used to see a "tardona", now things are changing and we would  more and more often see them in public with younger men. (Barbara d'Urso is probably a well known example).

Comment: However I wouldn't call Barbara D'Urso a *tardona*...

Comment: Conventionally, a Milf is younger than 60-70, as in the question, nor there is anything implying that she should be a socialite.

Comment: @DaG - if the English term is cougar as clarified in a comment, we are not talking about 60/70 year-old women, http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cougar.

Comment: Indeed, Gio, but the title of the question explicitly mentions “a woman in her sixties or seventies”. Perhaps the OP should decide which of the two is meant. In any case, “Milf” and “cougar” are not synonyms: «The simplest difference is that a MILF is someone who you (as the younger male) want to have sexual relations with, while a cougar wants to have sexual relations with you» (http://www.enkivillage.com/what-is-milf.html#affix-section-2).

Comment: @DaG - yes, though I've noticed that Milf is often used with the predatory connotation typical of a cougar "Attirano giovani uomini che rimangono affascinati dal loro charme e dall'indubbia esperienza. Perché si sa: esperienza è sinonimo di divertimento assicurato, ma senza complicazioni." http://questomeseidee.it/milf-cougar-o-gilf-sapete-cosa-significano/